How to uninstall Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 from cmd without affecting Visual Studio Professional 2019?
I need to uninstall Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 from the Windows command line terminal cmd but ensure that Visual Studio Professional 2019 remains installed.
I don't have the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer folder, so I don't have the vs_installer.exe for Enterprise 2022. Instead, I only have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe. I am concerned that running vs_installer.exe /uninstall /quiet /norestart with this path might uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2019, which I need to keep.
How can I uninstall Enterprise 2022 completely without affecting my Visual Studio Professional 2019 installation?

Why don’t you run it once without the /quite to see what would be uninstalled? You can just cancel the uninstallation

@Ramhound running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe" /uninstall /norestart It shows this window . Should I proceed with selecting Uninstall? Wouldn't it uninstall Professional 2019?

Why does it need to be done from cmd specifically?

@Destroy666 I prefer CLI. It is precise. it is repeatable. it is scriptable. It is mouse free...

Ok, but it's an uninstall that you do once. Or am I missing something? If you want to script it on X devices later, why not just test it on a single device where it's most irrelevant to potentially lose 2019 version?

Just use Visual Studio Installer UI to remove it, and move on with your life.

@spikey_richie sure, but which UI? What is the canonical way of uninstalling Enterprise 2022 completely and make sure the Professional 2019 is unharmed?

the vs_*.exe CLI functionalities are just awful. They do not work properly at all!

Start > Visual Studio Installer, wait for it to load a list of what's installed, then click More > Uninstall on the 2019 install.

here's what I have done so far:

First, verified that VS Enterprise 2022 isn't registered in the standard ways:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -all -products * -format json
wmic product where "name like '%%Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022%%'" get IdentifyingNumber


These commands don't show VS Enterprise 2022, so I tried uninstalling using the official installer:

curl -L -o vs_enterprise.exe "https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_enterprise.exe"
vs_enterprise.exe uninstall --installPath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise" --quiet --norestart


To verify if the uninstallation was successful:

Checked Windows Registry:

reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /f "Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022" /s


Checked installer logs:

dir "%TEMP%\dd_bootstrapper_*.log"


Because the installation directory still exists after successful uninstallation I ran:


rmdir /S /Q "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise"

This process should safely remove VS Enterprise 2022 while leaving VS Professional 2019 untouched, since they are installed in different locations and have separate registrations in the system.
